# Django model inheriting from different models, which each inherit from a single class

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I am creating a form with Django. This form's ModelForm is built upon multiple models that inherit from base models. The structure of the models is similar to this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("First name", max_length=20)
    middle_name = models.CharField("Middle name", max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField("Email address")
    phone = models.CharField("Phone number", max_length=16)
```

Is inherited by

```
class EmployerModel(BaseModel):
    company = models.CharField("Company", max_length=20)
```

and..

```
class AdvisorModel(BaseModel):
    department = models.CharField("Department", max_length=20)
```

which is contained in my highest level model (the model that is used in my ModelForm):

```
class FormModel(EmployerModel, AdvisorModel):
    another_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    and_another_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)

#...

class FormModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FormModel
```

---

Can I take this approach while making the form and avoid ORM errors because I have duplicate field names? Is there a way to separate and say; "THESE fields are for a 'Employer'; THESE fields are for an 'Advisor'?"

**EDIT**

It looks like I need to go with abstract base classes, but I don't know if that fixes the multiple inheritance problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go abstract with parent models, I've successfully written models with this kind of definition:

```
class Content(ModeratedModel, NullableGenericModel, RatedModel, PicturableModel, PrivacyModel, CommentableModel):
    pass
```

and `ModelForm`s using `Content` as a model work fine.